Make min and max value of sliderInput typeable Shiny
I would like to make the min and max value of the sliderInput typeable. So the user can slide the values but also should have the opportunity to type the values in the blue boxes of the values. Here is a simple reproducible example:
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("range", "Your range",
                min = 0, max = 1000, value = c(400, 500)),
)
  
server <- function(input, output) {
}
  
shinyApp(ui, server)

Output:

So now you can only slide the range but I would like to give the user also the option to type the value in the two blue boxes. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to make the sliderInput also typeable?

A workaround is to create two numeric inputs linked to the range slider:
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("obs_numeric1", "Min range value", min = 0, max = 1000, value = 400),
  numericInput("obs_numeric2", "Max range value", min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500),
  sliderInput("obs", "Range slider:",
              min = 0, max = 1000, value = c(400, 500)
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$obs, {
    updateNumericInput(session, "obs_numeric1", value = input$obs[1])
  })
  observeEvent(input$obs, {
    updateNumericInput(session, "obs_numeric2", value = input$obs[2])
  })
  observeEvent(input$obs_numeric1 | input$obs_numeric2, {
    updateSliderInput(session, "obs",
                      value = c(input$obs_numeric1, input$obs_numeric2))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Even the Ion Range Slider Jquery library used to generate the sliders suggests such technique to update range values, see here. That's also a request on their github page.

Thank you for your answer! This is indeed an option, though it is not exactly what I'm looking. But it is still an option, thanks!

Yes, I've been looking for this too, I will try to play with some JavaScript to edit the labels if I can find some time
